# How do I implement chained, monthly subscription payments using Stripe? (similar to Patreon)

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm building a crowdfunding platform where users subscribe monthly to different campaigns. I want it so all of the subscriptions are billed together (chained) on the first of the month. Patreon does something similar to this so I know this is possible, but I can't find anywhere in Stripe's documentation that addresses this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, as a crowdfunding platform, you need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to be able to accept payments on behalf of the campaign owners. You'd either use [Standalone](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts) accounts where the user has its own Stripe account that he connects to your platform or, if you're a platform in the US or Canada, [Managed](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts) accounts where you create the account for your user.

This will allow you to create [charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#creating-payments) or [subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#creating-subscriptions) on their behalf so that the funds get sent to them directly and you can take an [application fee](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#collecting-fees) for your platform.

As for the ability to charge on the first of the month, this is done through [trial periods](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#working-with-trials). When you create the subscription through the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription), you'd pass the `trial_end` parameter set to a timestamp of the day you want their first charge to happen. That way, the customers doesn't get charged anything until the 1st of next month for example.